# Detect data type of incoming request

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm using a objectoutputstream to send and receive data for known devices, but it might be possible in my case that also other requests with "String"-Streams might on the InputStream of the socket.

What is the best way to detect if the incoming stream can be handled by an ObjectInputStream or needs to be red over a normal bufferedreader/inputreader.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: One does not guess the incoming message. You should come with a very well protocol, and stop working this way to guess the incoming possible type.

Comment: well it is actuall a well defined protocol. It is just possible that on the same ip/port two different types of requests needed to be handled by the server, which could be either a String Stream or an Object Stream

Comment: Well so it's not well defined. One solution to make it well defined is send one flag before you send the actual data(e.g. a byte which 0 means it's object, and 1 as it's 0), then read the next data as it is. I also suggest you get rid of too much java thing, and go with something more common like JSON/XML over java object marshalling, it will help you too much to have multiple clients with different platforms when java is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a string as an object through a objectoutputsteam and on the other side you use instanceof to check if it is a string.If its not, you can keep checking using instanceof to find what class the object sent through is. Once you find the right Class you have to cast the object to that class.

Answer (score 0):

After long back'n forth we decided to change the protocol. As mentioned by @user8245293 is actually a bit messy. It poses a security problem and would implement a quirky solution by detecting the stream type.

For us the best solution seemed to be - if others are interested - to do introduce light handshake protocol with some header information to arrange the stream type.